# On an average what is the number of users getting added to puzzling SE?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

> On an average what is the number of users getting added to puzzling SE.
>
> How many new users are getting added in the recent times ?
>
> Any Data about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/483472/new-users-by-month#graph), here's a graph of new users over time (by week):

[image]

And here's one by month from [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/452657/new-users-per-month#graph):

[image]

(Not sure *what* happened in late November of 2014! I wasn't around here then.)

Comment: Ah, I see you've plotted the Dark Ages of Puzzling... ;)

Comment: Ohh.. So, that may-June 2016 had the highest number of users in PSE. Pretty cool...